# PHP can not make directory in daemon mode

Tags: php, daemon, swoole

I'm using swoole/HTTP server, and I set it on daemon:1 to make it work on the background but there is a problem.

When I try to make a directory in this mode, PHP can't do that, and there is no swoole error log.

Comment: It's probably a permissions problem. Make sure the username the daemon uses has permission to create the directory. Also confirm that it's creating the directory in the location you expect.

Comment: @Barmar location is correct and directory and php user is root can you specify how can i set permission for daemon?thanks.

Comment: root should not be prohibited from making directories anywhere. Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` so that warning messages get printed.

Comment: @Barmar problem is in daeom mode i can not see errors because its not running in any page or even terminal, and there is no swoole error either.

Comment: You can configure a log file in `php.ini` and warning messages will go there.